# Transpose dataframe as pattern changes in a column R

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a data frame in R which looks like this with 3 columns

```
  col1 col2 col3
    A   11   203
    A   12   205
    C   25   306
    C   65   745
```

Desired output: Only the third column transposed when the pattern in first column changes.
I am new to R.

```
203   205
306   745
```

I tried `t(data)` but then it transposed the whole data.

For only the third column I tried `t(data$col3)` but this transposes the whole third column. I know I am close but couldn't make it.Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way in Base-R

```
t(sapply(split(df,df[,1]), function(x) x[,3]))

  [,1] [,2]
A  203  205
C  306  745
```

Here, `split` is dividing the dataframe into smaller dataframes according to the letters in your first column. Then we pass a custom `function(x)` to those split dataframes using `sapply`. The custom function simply calls the values in the third column with `x[,3]`.

Comment: Your code is giving the slightly wrong output. The output provided by your code has to be transposed and then I get the output that I want. `t(sapply(split(df,df[,1]), function(x) x[,3]))`

Comment: You're right! I forgot to transpose the result. I've edited the answer to add that in.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The code provided by @Daniel O works fine but it is giving slightly wrong output. For this to work correctly I just transposed the output of the code:

```
t(sapply(split(df,df[,1]), function(x) x[,3]))

    [,1]    [,2]
A   203     205
C   306     745
```

Another method to obtain a list of this output will be to use `lapply`

```
lapply(split(Afatinib,Afatinib[,1]), function(x) x[,3])
```